# Extract all characters to the left of a list of possible characters

Tags: r, string, extract

I have a series of strings in a dataframe like the ones below:

```
item_time<-c("pink dress july noon", "shirt early september morning", "purple dress 
april", "tall purple shoes february")
```

And I want to extract all the characters to the left of a list of possible characters like these:

```
time<-c("january", "january night", "february","march","april","may", "may 
morning", "june","july", "july noon","august","september","early september morning", 
"october","november","december")
```

The result I want would look like this:

```
[1] pink dress
[2] shirt
[3] purple dress
[4] tall purple shoes
```

I can't separate them by spaces as there are varying number of words in the time and item lists. I also don't have a symbol that separates them. I feel that there should be a quite simple and elegant way of solving this but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` in Base R:

```
sapply(strsplit(item_time, split=paste0("\\s", time, collapse="|")), `[`, 1)
# [1] "pink dress"        "shirt"             "purple dress"      "tall purple shoes"
```

**Notes:**

I first collapse the `time` vector and separate each term by `|`, then use that to split `item_time` with `strsplit`. Since the split argument in `strsplit` accepts regular expressions, it will interpret `|` as an OR operator effectively spliting `item_time` whenever it sees one of the terms in `time`. `sapply(...,`[`, 1)` then look at each element of the list and extract the first element, which will be the left most string after the split.

Comment: @IsaNavarro Glad that my solution helped. Feel free to accept the answer you find the most helpful by clicking on the grey check mark under the downvote button.

Comment: follow up question: what part of the code would change if I had a similar situation but wanted to extract all the characters to the right (instead of to the left). Thanks again!

Comment: @IsaNavarro It's a little trickier since you would like to extract the last element. So something like the following would work **assuming there is always some string to the right**: `sapply(strsplit(item_time, split=paste0(time, "\\s", collapse="|")), function(x) x[length(x)])` You need to decide what should happen if there is nothing to the right (or left for that matter).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub` as it is vectorized

```
sub(paste0("\\s*",time,".*",collapse="|"),"",item_time)
[1] "pink dress"        "shirt"             "purple dress"      "tall purple shoes"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to make the vector of possible characters into a regular expression pattern and use that to extract the right strings, as below.

This works by using `|` to separate all options for the possible characters, and then placing them inside a lookahead `(?= )`. This tries to match patterns that precede the list of options. Then we just add `^.*` to collect the entire string before the list of times, starting at the beginning.

Note that this will fail if any of the options in `time` have special characters, and will return `NA` if no option in `time` is found in an entry of `item_time`.

```r
item_time <- c(
  "pink dress july noon", "shirt september morning",
  "purple dress april", "tall purple shoes february"
)

time <- c(
  "january", "january night", "february", "march", "april", "may",
  "may morning", "june", "july", "july noon", "august", "september",
  "september morning", "october", "november", "december"
)

library(stringr)
pattern <- time %>%
  str_c(collapse = "|") %>%
  str_c("^.*(?= (", ., "))")

item_time %>%
  str_extract(pattern)
#> [1] "pink dress"        "shirt"             "purple dress"     
#> [4] "tall purple shoes"
```

Created on 2018-08-13 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).